# Fix url in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

so I have done a AJAX call in Laravel project and in a method I want to return a output.

This is the output

```
$output = ' <div class="col-xs-12 col-width">
                                <div class="single-product mb-30">
                                    <div class="single-product-item clearfix">
                                        <div class="single-product-img clearfix">
                                            <a href=\"{{route(\'product_details\',' . $product->slug . ')}}\">
                                                <img class="primary-image" src="'.env('PRODUCT_URL'). $product->image . '" style="width: 200px;height: 240px" alt="">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="single-product-info clearfix">
                                            <h3><a href="{{route(\'product_details\','.$product->slug.')}}">' . $product->name . '</a></h3>
                                            <div class="pro-price">
                                          ' . $new . '
                                         </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="new-sale">                
                                    ' . $offer . '
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
```

When i click the product I see the route:

> /"%7B%7Burl('product_details',test)%7D%7D/"

What should I do to fix the quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<a href="{{route(\'product_details\','.$product->slug.')}}">
```

by

```
<a href="' . route('product_details', $product->slug) . '">
```

Final result:

```
$output = ' <div class="col-xs-12 col-width">
   <div class="single-product mb-30">
      <div class="single-product-item clearfix">
          <div class="single-product-img clearfix">
             <a href="' . route('product_details', $product->slug) . '">
                <img class="primary-image" src="'.env('PRODUCT_URL'). $product->image . '" style="width: 200px;height: 240px" alt="">
             </a>
       </div>

 <div class="single-product-info clearfix">
     <h3><a href="' . route('product_details', $product->slug) . '">' . $product->name . '</a></h3>
     <div class="pro-price">
         ' . $new . '
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="new-sale">                
 ' . $offer . '
  </div>
</div>
</div>';
```

Then it will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use blade outside the blade templates, use standard php. so

```
'<a href=\"'.route('product_details',$product->slug).'\">'
```

instead of

```
'<a href=\"{{route(\'product_details\',' . $product->slug . ')}}\">'
```